# Creating Classes and Outputting

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to create a person class, enter details and output the specific person class however at the moment i just have a bunch of variables and I'm outputting from the variables, not the class

```
class Person:

def __init__(self, _firstname, _surname, d, m, y):
    self._firstname = _firstname
    self._surname = _surname
    self.d = d
    self.m = m
    self.y = y


john = Person('John','Lennon','8','10','1940')
paul = Person('Paul','McCartney','7','7','1940')


john._firstname = 'John'
john._surname = 'Lennon'
john.d = '8th'
john.m = 'October'
john.y = '1940'


paul._firstname = 'Paul'
paul._surname = 'McCartney'
paul._day = '18'
paul._month = '6'
paul._year = '1943'

print('{} {} \n{} {} {}'.format(john._firstname, 
john._surname, john.d, john.m, john.y))
```

As you can see in the code I've simply made variables, assigned something to the variable, and printed the variable, I'm not sure how to use the class system correctly, any help would be great thank you

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: i need to output a class, not from variables

Comment: What do you mean by "output a class"?

Comment: i need to add "john" to a class, and be able to output john by simply printing "john" instead of print(john._firstname) etc ...

Comment: Please also fix your indentation of the `__init__` method!

Comment: Your question is not clear. It seems you are using incorrect terms ("output a class"?) . Can you reformulate?

Comment: I think the best would be to give an example of the output you want, and maybe an example of how you expect you should be able to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to just print the class instance and receive a formatted output. For this you need to implement this method in the class:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return '{} {} \n{} {} {}'.format(john._firstname, john._surname, john.d, john.m, john.y)
```

Then you can just print the class instance:

```
print(john)
```

So this would be the complete code:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, _firstname, _surname, d, m, y):
        self._firstname = _firstname
        self._surname = _surname
        self.d = d
        self.m = m
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} {} \n{} {} {}'.format(john._firstname, john._surname, john.d, john.m, john.y)


john = Person('John','Lennon','8','10','1940')
paul = Person('Paul','McCartney','7','7','1940')


john._firstname = 'John'
john._surname = 'Lennon'
john.d = '8th'
john.m = 'October'
john.y = '1940'


paul._firstname = 'Paul'
paul._surname = 'McCartney'
paul._day = '18'
paul._month = '6'
paul._year = '1943'

print('{} {} \n{} {} {}'.format(john._firstname, john._surname, john.d,      john.m, john.y))
print(john)
```